# Как определить расширение файла?

Tags: java, android, файловая-система

Я пытаюсь сделать свой файловый менеджер и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Когда я пытаюсь выбрать файл, а не директорию, то моя программа слетает. Можете подсказать, как сделать так, что бы программа допускала открытие только директорий. Если конкретно, то мне нужно узнать есть ли какие-то алгоритмы или методы для определения расширения файлов.

```
/*Класс который отвечает за работу файлового менеджера*/
public class FileManager extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView listOfDirs;
    String [] paths = {"/storage/emulated/0/", "/storage/extSdCard/"};
    String currentPath = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_manager);

        listOfDirs = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listOfDirs.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                paths);
        listOfDirs.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        String localPath = paths[position];/*Здесь я определяю какую диру выбрал юзер и осуществляю переход в эту диру*/ 

        transition(localPath);//Сам переход

        listOfDirs.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                paths)); /*Вывод на экран директорий, находящихся по заданному пути*/
    }


    void transition(String currentDirectory){
        if(currentPath.equals("")){ //Проверяет установлен ли первичный путь
            currentPath = currentDirectory;
        }
        else {
            currentPath = currentPath + currentDirectory;
        }

        File file = new File(currentPath);
        paths = file.list();//Парсинг директории и занесение всех ее элементов в массив
    }
}
```

Comment: Может быть вам нужно определять что некий объект ФС является директорией?

Comment: Ну или так. Да, скорее всего так будет правильнее.

Comment: File file = new File(path);
boolean isDirectory = file.isDirectory();

Comment: Благодарю, но все же. Можно ли как-то узнать расширение файла?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проще всего искать до последней точки и обрезать все до нее.

Для этого существует функция lastIndexOf.

Функция обрезающая расширение:

```
private static String getFileExtension(String mystr) {
    int index = mystr.indexOf('.');
    return index == -1? null : mystr.substring(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = "file.txt";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\.\\w+$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(path);
m.find();
String ext = m.group();
System.out.println(path + " " + ext);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Path path = Paths.get("foo/bar.java")
if (path.endsWith(".java")){
    //Do stuff
}
```